Large fastcgi responses not caching. Is there a limit?
I'm using Nginx fastcgi cache.
Some URLs seem not to cache. It appears this may be related to the response size. Responses over about 5MB don't go into the cache. I can't find anything else to differentiate successful cached responses from unsuccessful ones.
Is there a ceiling? If so, what directives is it based on?
The only non-default settings I've enabled are as follows:
fastcgi_cache_path /foo keys_zone=foo:100m inactive=1d use_temp_path=off max_size=1g min_free=500m;

fastcgi_cache_key  $request_method:$request_uri:$http_authorization;
fastcgi_cache_lock on;
fastcgi_cache_revalidate on;
fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;

Everything else is default. I've not changed anything else to do with buffers or temp files.
